# How do I address the email to acknowledge a rejection email which has been sent from a 'general' account?

Tags: interviewing, rejection

I had 3 onsite interviews including one with the VP yesterday.

I followed up after each interview to thank the interviewer(s). A lady from their HR department (I assume) had been emailing me about the interview process but this rejection email did not specify a sender.

**Any ideas on how/who to address it to and the content?**

Answer (score 11):

Send the response to the same person who you had been communicating with until now. What has likely happened here is the HR person submitted the "Reject" decision to a tool, which sent out an auto-generated email.

Keep the response short and to the point. Thank them for the opportunity and mention one (or at most two) interesting things you learned about the company from the interview. You may also express your interest in being contacted for any future opportunities (assuming you *are* interested, of course).

> Hello Jane,
>
> I have received an email stating that my job application for Senior Engineer has been rejected. I would like to thank you and everyone who interviewed me for their time. I was amazed to learn that Acme Corporation manufactures the world's best Roadrunner catching contraptions.
>
> I look forward to opportunities to work with Acme Corporation in the future.
>
> Regards,
>   hongkongvader

An additional benefit of sending this response is if the rejection mail was sent in error, and you are still in consideration, the HR person can fix the miscommunication.

Comment: Strange thing, I emailed the lady who had been in touch with me. But then I received a message on Linkedin from the VP who had interviewed me yesterday thanking me for coming in and that he looks forward to speaking to me next week. When the interview ended yesterday, he mentioned that he would talk to the other interviewers TODAY and they will get back to me next week. Could the email I received earlier be a mistake or is it just the HR rejecting me?

Comment: That sounds like someone has made a mistake ;) Patience...

Comment: @carrdelling yes i'll be patient though it was a terrible start to my day haha

Comment: @hongkongvader Don't be patient. If you haven't already reached out since your last contact do so now to explain that you got a rejection mail and that, while you of course understand if they decided not to continue with your application, are wondering if there was a misunderstanding citing what you were told about the next steps. And once you've done that I suggest editing that information from your comment into your question. :)

Comment: Agree with @Lilienthal. It may have been a mistake on this part, and in that case they may not be aware of it; in that case they may believe that your previous e-mail meant that you were no longer interested in the position. They already have made a mistake (either in their first email or the second one), so take all of the necessary steps to ensure that they do not make another one and that there is no confussion.

Comment: @Lilienthal I would concur and suggest you elevate that to an answer.  Patience can be a virtue, but in this case too much patience can kill your chances.  Contacting them will not hurt your chances, if they have already eliminated you, you are eliminated and showing more interest will not look bad.  But if the contact was in error, and you do not respond, then the error could become truth due to perceived lack of interest.  Be polite, express that you are interested and hoped/hope to move forward, but do not let it just slide.

Comment: @dlb MaskedMan can add it to his answer if he wants but to be posted on its own the original question should also be edited. I suppose I could do it myself but I think this is also a question we get regularly in various forms and I think there are better and more general questions on that on the site.