# How to thank a Vice President for an interview when rejected for the position?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, rejection

I went through multiple interviews with a firm culminating in a final interview with the VP. It seemed like a final step to just seal the deal and I had a great conversation for 90+ minutes where we even discussed which team I could join. He said that he would discuss with the other managers who had interviewed me the next day and they would get back to me next week. The very first thing next morning I receive a rejection email so I was a little surprised and then later in the afternoon the VP replied to my thank you message on LinkedIn where he said that he was looking forward to speaking to me the next week. Should I respond to him?

Comment: Whom did you receive rejection email from ? HR ? Any Senior/Manager ? Was it a kind of *automatic response* or a clearly identified sender ?

Comment: Do you think that the VP is unaware that you have not been hired? Or do you have another reason why you'd be speaking to the VP next week?

Comment: No other reason to speak to the VP, the message seemed one of those system generated messages. I emailed the recruitment lady I had been speaking to and she said that after reviewing my application and my interview with the VP they won't be moving forward to it. So i am confused as to why he had a different time frame and then brought it up again when he messaged me.

Comment: @hongkongvader How is this different from [your other question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95044/how-do-i-address-the-email-to-acknowledge-a-rejection-email-which-has-been-sent)?

Comment: Please submit only one post per question.  That being said, not getting the job is not being "rejected."  It means that you weren't the best candidate.  It doesn't mean you weren't suitable or acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I respond to him?

Yes, unless you did not like at all the interview process/the company.

From what you say, it seems that they are not going to consider you for the position, but the VP may be interested in offering you something else.

I would definitely go there - just consider it as another step in the interview process, and don't sell yourself too short if he makes you a different offer.

Comment: thanks! I get the feeling that it is the HR who have rejected me since the lady I had been in touch with over interviews clarified that yes after my interview with the VP they had decided to not move forward with my application. Yet AFTER that rejection email the VP mentioned talking next week.

Answer (score 3):

My current boss is very fond of telling a story about how he was in the middle of an interview with the VP and CFO of a company, and receiving an email(during the interview) that he'd been rejected. This was an automated response that he shouldn't have received.

That being said, if the VP is stating that he's looking forward to meeting with you still next week, there is nothing wrong with replying to him. There's two scenarios here. 1.) It was an automated response sent on accident, and you were in fact not meant to receive it. 2.) It was sent genuinely and the VP is unaware. The worst thing that can happen is that you were in fact rejected. The best thing is you could be on the receiving end of an offer.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciating people for spending their time with you is just a basic courtesy. When a school teacher gives student a failure  grade - he is just doing his job! So it is not the end of the world.

If VP has specifically asked you to meet - leave your baggage for the last interview aside and just go with an open mind just to listen to him. You might be there for a surprise or he might just want some other help.

We are typically in a hyper-networked-world. So while a person X may or may not be able to hire in a company Y, he may still carry a positive view about you when he is around in some other company or even same company different context.

Comment: I have been thinking that that is probably what is going on. Still find it strange that we finished our interview at the end of the day where he said he would discuss with his colleagues the next day and then get back to me next week but at 930 next morning i have a rejection email

Comment: If people have a problem with question or answer, I am open to criticism. But If you down-vote, do explain what makes you frown upon that question or answer. Plain simple down votes without any reason is plain enmity than any criticism. 
It is a very bad cultural in workplace which I rarely see in other stack-exchange site.